# Hide parent view when displayen nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show, angular-ui-router

I want to hide a list of users when I to display the nested view users.info .
I wrote this code
**HTML**

```
<div ng-hide="hide">
the list of users...
<a ui-sref="users.info"> <button ng-click="hideUsersList()"> </a>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.hideList = function hideList() 
{$scope.hide=true;};
```

it works and hide the list when I click on the button, but the problem is when I use the back button in the browser, hide still 'true' and I get a blank page

Comment: What if you instantiated $scope.hide = false in your controller?

Comment: it's already initiated

Comment: can post a plunkr or jsfiddle ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only hide the DOM element, the scope remains and the hide variable is still attached to it with the latest value.

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is maybe switching the nested views when moving between states, that way each time you move to a new state you'll be instantiating a new controller and a new scope.

[Nested States, Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)